# When does an `open` command terminate?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a bash script which creates a temp PDF file, opens it in Skim, then removes it and exits. The last lines of the script are:

```
open -a Skim -W "$PDFFILE"
rm "$PDFFILE"
```

This successfully opens the PDF in Skim, but then even after I close the Skim window, the script gets stuck and does not execute the remove command. How can I get it to move on to the last line when I close the window?

Answer (score 2):

`open` in this case (`-W`) won't exit until the application indicated exits. Simply closing a window apparently does not exit Skim; you'll have to make sure you actually quit the application.

Comment: Is there a different option to exit when the window closes? If I already have Skim open with a different document, I wouldn't want to have to close that window as well to get an unrelated process to finish....

Comment: You can use `-n` to open a fresh instance of Skim; you still have to quit to get `open` to exit, but you won't be quitting an application that possibly has other documents open as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another untested solution. If you don't mind waiting till Skim exits to do the deletion but still wish your script to continue (or exit) have the script do `open` & `rm` in the background:

```
(open -a Skim -W "$PDFFILE"; rm "$PDFFILE")&
```

That will run the two commands sequentially in a background shell while your script continues.

Comment: Cool idea! You have a double quote missing at the end, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Skim" to documents'
```

it will tell you a list of documents that are actively being edited in `Skim`.

So, if you know the name of the document you told `Skim` to open, you can presumably wait in a loop (maybe with a short delay in it) in `bash` till that document is no longer open - i.e. no longer in the list.

It would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PDFFILE="/Users/mark/Desktop/OpenCV_2_Computer_Vision_Application_Programming_Cookbook.pdf"
PDFBASE=$(basename "$PDFFILE")
open -a Skim "$PDFFILE" &
while :; do
   osascript -e 'tell application "Skim" to documents' | grep "$PDFBASE" || break
   sleep 1
done
```